# How to pick up points of SmoothHistogram

Tags: histograms

I have some data, and I used SmoothHistogram to obtain a curve.

[image]

Now I would like to pick up several points on the curve such that I can fit this curve to a function. I get stuck with picking up points.
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Post the code you used to generate the plot please.

Comment: What function do you have in mind?  I ask for two reasons:  (1) If you have some particular probability density function in mind, you'd be better off using the original data and use maximum likelihood and (2) If you're considering a regression, note that the variance about the curve will not be equal across all values (which is usually the default assumption for most regression functions).

Comment: If your raw data is in `x`, then you can generate a list of points with `skd = SmoothKernelDistribution[x];
Table[{y, PDF[skd, y]}, {y, 0, 10, 0.01}]` (but adjusting the `y` values to match what you need).  That way you have explicit control as to the values of `y` that you want the pdf to be evaluated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the points, you can get them out of the Graphics object (remember that everything in Mathematica is a list of lists):

```
rands=RandomReal[1, 1000];
pts=SmoothHistogram[rands][[1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1]]
ListPlot[pts]
```

[image: ListPlot of the smoothed histogram points]